# My c# code doesn't compile when in VScode

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using an M1 Macbook while using VScode. I'm fairly new to coding. vscode seems to get stuck in a loop and doesn't compile my code whenever I use structs in C#

```
using System;

public struct Person
{
  public string firstName;
  public string SurName;
  public string MiddleName;
}

namespace anuk
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person;
            person.firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            person.SurName = Console.ReadLine();
            person.MiddleName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(person.firstName);
            Console.WriteLine(person.SurName);
            Console.WriteLine(person.MiddleName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you made that a struct instead of a class?

Comment: Try changing `Person person;` to `Person person = new Person() ;` -  which you would need for a class

Comment: Does the code compile from the command line? It certainly does on my Windows machine just with csc - the code is "fine". (Not code I'd write, but it's valid code.)

Comment: If it doesn't compile you should see an error code. Please share it.

Comment: @GertArnold apparently the OP doesn't get any error but "vscode seems to get stuck in a loop" - which I read as "never finishes"